# Changing filenames for Bootstrap 4.5 examples

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

Looking to use one of the examples for Bootstrap 4.5, but whenever I change the filename of the html file or the css file for the example, it breaks the formatting link for the example page. How can I duplicate the original example files and alter the names (to something like "my_page.html" or "my_page.css" for example) without changing the page itself?

Answer (score 0):

If you change the name of your stylesheet (CSS), you also have to update it in your HTML, otherwise it will point your stylesheet to the old name and will break. This works the same for all other file resources you are linking to a HTML page, such as other HTML pages, images, scripts etc.

**UPDATE WITH AN EXAMPLE:**

Lets say I have three files: `index.html`, `contact.html` and `stylesheet.css`. In my `index.html` and `contact.html` pages, they might have the following code:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<a href="contact.html">Contact me</a>

<!-- contact.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

Both pages have a link to the stylesheet, and each page has a link to the other page.

Now, I want to change the name of my stylesheet to `awesome-style.css`, and my contact page to `awesome-contact.html`. I would have to make the following changes to my HTML pages:

```html
<!-- index.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="awesome-style.css">
<a href="awesome-contact.html">Contact me</a>

<!-- awesome-contact.html -->
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="awesome-style.css">
<a href="index.html">Home</a>
```

I have changed three lines of code here. The stylesheet has to be changed in all HTML pages for your styling to still apply to all pages. In my `index.html` page, I have changed the link from `contact.html` to `awesome.contact.html` so it will still link to the correct HTML page.

I have never had to change any code in `awesome-style.css`, as you never tell it what HTML documents you will be using it in.

Comment: And what if I want to change the name of both files? That's usually where things break for me

Comment: And where in the HTML and CSS files specifically would I make that update?

Comment: I've updated my answer with an example in code that should help :)

Comment: Appreciate the edits, however when I create a new html page, `my_page.html` for example, and I try to link back to the original css file in another folder through the `href` tag, the connection breaks even though I'm copying the entire path of the css file itself and pasting it into `href` tag. For reference, the Bootstrap example I'm trying to use is the Carousel page. So even though I have a new html page `my_page.html` -- I'm still trying to link it back to the original `carousel.css` stylesheet.

Comment: Links are relative, so depending on where they are you have to tell it what folder it is in. If your html page is above your css file in your directory structure, include the folder the css file is in. If your css file is above your html file, you have to use `../style.css` to locate your css file in the directory above. If your css file is in the root of your working directory, you can do `/style.css`.